# Why does my Java code cause netbeans to freeze

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans

I have been working on a piece of work and when I try to run it, my IDE freezes and I got to use the task manager to close it.

Any idea why?  I know it has something to do with an iterator and while loop I was using.

Can anybody spot it?  Below part of the servlet code:

```
try {
        List<FileItem> fields = upload.parseRequest(request);

        Iterator<FileItem> it = fields.iterator();




        //starting conversion from file to sample


        //creating a container to hold the samples
        ArrayList<sample> samplelist = new ArrayList();

        while (it.hasNext()) {

            sample c = new sample();
            FileItem fileItem = it.next();

            c.setFileName(fileItem.getName());
            c.setPayload(fileItem.getString());
            samplelist.add(c);
        }

        //looping through uploaded samples to split code into lines
        for (int i = 0; i < samplelist.size(); i++) {
            sample current = new sample();
            current = samplelist.get(i);

            //splitting whole code block into lines based on ;
            String[] temp;
            temp = current.getPayload().split(";");

            //going through split lines and adding them to the sample's rawcode
            //arraylist after checking for for loops
            for (int j = 0; j < temp.length; j++) {

                // current.Raw_Code.add(temp[j]);
                String current_line = temp[j];




                current.Raw_Code.add(current_line);

            }




        }

//testing
        System.out.print("starting testing");
        for (int i = 0; i < samplelist.size(); i++) {
            sample current = new sample();
            current = samplelist.get(i);
            System.out.print("File name <br/>");
            current.getFileName();
            System.out.print("lines detected <br/>");

            Iterator itr = current.Raw_Code.iterator();

           //this while loop started to cause the problem

             while(itr.hasNext()){
             System.out.print("x");   
             }
        }




    } catch (FileUploadException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    out.close();
    return;
```

Comment: use step by step debugger

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Missing itr.next() in that place

Answer (score 10):

Right here:

```
while(itr.hasNext()){
    System.out.print("x");   
}
```

You aren't calling `itr.next()` so the iterator isn't iterating. :) Adding `itr.next()` inside of your `while` loop will correct the issue.

Comment: this is one of those: "let the cpu burn!" problems :)

Answer (score 1):

Your while is an infinite loop - the iterator always hasNext because it never iterates... so it just keeps on going.

On another note, whenever the IDE crashes you should think "infinite loop as it is a common side-effect of that programming problem.